# Is there an ebib-like bibliography manager for emacs designed for biblatex?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, bibtex, emacs

I've been using ebib to manage my .bib files, but I've just switched over from using bibtex to using biblatex & biber to actually generate the bibliographies in documents. Obviously the file format is still the same since I'm still just using .bib files, but a couple of things make ebib non-ideal:

1. the required fields for the bibliography types aren't all the same; e.g., for @article entries biblatex expects "journaltitle" rather than just "journal"
2. ebib is not aware of biber's context-sensitive handling of crossref fields; e.g., biber will make the title field of a @collection item the booktitle field of an @incollection item that refers to it with crossref.

The first of these is not really a big deal, but the second would take more work to remedy. I have a *lot* of cross-references in my bib file and don't really want to undertake a bunch of elisp hacking, welcome as the procrastination would be.

Anyone know of a package for emacs that does biber-like context-sensitive crossref stuff?

Comment: I think this question should be asked at the developer site http://sourceforge.net/projects/ebib/

Comment: Asked: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3517715&group_id=115723&atid=672494

Comment: nice! thanks, I should've been more aggressive about this myself, the ebib devs have been pretty responsive before.

Comment: There's an ebib package foir emacs http://ebib.sourceforge.net/manual/ebib-manual.html but I've never used it, and don't know if it handles cross references the way you want.

Comment: While this is a good idea, it's essentially a feature request. That's not something that can make a good Q&A post, so I've closed. Request reopening if you feel this is not right.